# How to update a global variable in Swift by reference?

Tags: swift

My question is simple in the C language, just access the global variable using access with a pointer -

```
demoFunc(int *someVar) {

    *someVar = 1234;

    return;
}
```

How do you do this in Swift? For simplicity and clarity, how do you do this for the following code?

```
class Example {

    var globalInt : Int = 0;

    func someMain() {

        self.modifyVar(?&globalInt?);  //Q: How do you do this?

        return;
    }


    func modifyVar(?&someVar?) {       //Q: ?

        someVar = 1234;                //Q: ?

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried using 'inout' but this only worked for local function variables" Huh?

Comment: comment removed - it was added during debug, and makes no sense now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
var toto = 3

class Example {
    var globalInt = 0
    
    func someMain() {
        self.modifyVar(&globalInt)
    }
    
    func modifyVar(inout someVar: Int) {
        someVar = 1234
    }
}

let vc = Example()

print(vc.globalInt)
vc.someMain()
print(vc.globalInt)

print(toto)
vc.modifyVar(&toto)
print(toto)
```

produces

> 0
>
> 1234
>
> 3
>
> 1234